# Showing WKT multipolygon in Mapserver results msGEOSError?

Tags: mapserver, well-known-text

I have multipolygon WKT and I want to show it as a layer in Mapserver, I followed Mapserver as in this link http://mapserver.org/mapfile/feature.html but I can see it didn't mention MULTIPOLYGON as supported feature and if I try to add MULTIPOLYGON WKT layer, I am getting below error:

```
[MapServer Error]: msGEOSError():0'ƒ╖▀_tΦ≡^☺ÇΘ^☺∞µ^☺Φ≡^☺0v`♦⌠≡^☺↑τ^☺♦▀_t0v`♦Φ≡^☺
```

Is there any other way ?

Comment: Is everything ok with a polygon wkt?

Comment: Yes, I can see data if **POLYGON**

Comment: GEOS error may mean that the multipolygon WKT is not valid. Add it into your question.

Comment: @user30184 I have add it, but already it seems MULTIPOLYGON WKT is not supported in mapserver. even I tried to add several lines of POLYGON but usually it draw first one only.

Comment: At least you should be able to have several polygons if you make a new FEATURE for each http://www.mapserver.org/input/vector/inline.html.

Comment: @user30184 you are right , I have used the inline for polygons at beginning but later I have data with multi polygons but I was assigning them as one feature, but adding them as multiple feature should be another way to tackle the problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created FEATURE for each polygon instead of showing them as one multipolygon.

**Example:**

```
FEATURE     
    POINTS           
        13586.1053343116510000 47310.9304744951590000
        13568.9927608650720000 47365.3396823765870000
        13427.0848528728730000 47398.8942616062700000
        13351.4186791848300000 47264.5609337644560000
        13586.1053343116510000 47310.9304744951590000      
    END 
END

FEATURE     
    POINTS           
        13384.1258640760640000 47219.0044976659560000
        13420.0943155333570000 47168.9055831361550000
        13581.5757280762030000 47189.8771951547020000
        13384.1258640760640000 47219.0044976659560000      
    END 
END
```

**Reference:**
http://www.mapserver.org/input/vector/inline.html

Comment: Answered by @user30184 in questions' comments